# Java array objects "null"

Tags: java, arrays

I have problem with my integer arrays, for example one. I have class with objects, and i have different class, where these objects are incremented after button click, but **I got "null" values and NullPointerExpection.** I had this all working, when i hade just, for example "int Money;", but my codes was 12000 lines, and i tried to make it easier to read, etc. But now with array they don't work. **I got working this thing with For Loops** , but how I understand, i can't make it with loops, because i want to later load these values from savefile.

**CarMainClass (This one doesn't work) :**

```
  package Clicker;

    public class MainHolder {

    public Integer main[] = new Integer[8];

    public MainHolder(){


    }

    public void MainMaker(int k){


    }

    public void MakeMain(){

        MainMaker(0); // Money

        MainMaker(0); // Money Clicks

        MainMaker(0); // Boxes

        MainMaker(0); // Boxes Clicks

        MainMaker(1); // Boxes Level

        MainMaker(1); // Player Level

        MainMaker(1); // Garage Level

        MainMaker(0); // Garage Slots

    }
}
```

**CarMainClass (That works, with for loop) :**

```
 package Clicker;

    public class MainHolder {

    public Integer main[];

    public MainHolder(){

        main = new Integer[8];

                for(int i=0; i <8;i ++){
                    if(i ==4 || i ==5 || i ==6){
                        MainMaker(1,i);

                    }else{
                        MainMaker(0,i);
                    }
                }   

    }

    public void MainMaker(int k,int p){

        main[p] = k;

    }

    public void MakeMain(){

    }
}
```

**And button :**

```
//Money Button Click
    if(ae.getSource() == jbtnMoney) {

        CarMain.main[0] += 1;   
        MoneyLabel.setText("Money: " + CarMain.main[0]);
        CarMain.main[1] += 1;     
        MoneyClicksLabel.setText("Money Clicks: " + CarMain.main[1]);
    }
```

**Application GUI when working :** [WorkingImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHXVg.png)

**Application GUI when dosn't work + error :** [NoWorkingImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmjMQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a full code of CarMainClass? It seems that the method MainMaker doesn't contain any executable code so it doesn't do anything when you call it. The button click is ok.
The initialised array is empty - contains only null values and that is why it returns null - when you reference the value on the GUI.
You need to change it to this (I assume that each number describes object):

package Clicker;

```
public class MainHolder {

public Integer main[] = new Integer[8];

public MainHolder(){
  MakeMain();
}
public void MainMaker(int k,int p){

    main[p] = k;

}
public void MakeMain(){

    MainMaker(0,0); // Money

    MainMaker(0,1); // Money Clicks

    MainMaker(0,2); // Boxes

    MainMaker(0,3); // Boxes Clicks

    MainMaker(1,4); // Boxes Level

    MainMaker(1,5); // Player Level

    MainMaker(1,6); // Garage Level

    MainMaker(0,7); // Garage Slots

}
```

}

But your solution to use loops make actually more sense. Why you can't store it into a file? You should define the the integers which you use to describe the application as constants - final Integer money = 0 and so on. 
You can store the values into a file and use the index to map the values to the corresponding values. Or store it as map.

Comment: Yes, that is full code, made like, your example, still same problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you call the MakeMain method? As previously the init of the array is part of the MainHolder constructor. Add public MainHolder(){ MakeMain(); }

Comment: Have you tried again? I have updated the original post with the init.